# Process microphone audio samples of Web Audio API

Tags: web-audio-api

I am trying to get the audio samples of my microphone via Web Audio using this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script>
    function start() {
        let button = document.getElementById("start");
        button.disabled = true;

        let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: {
                echoCancellation: false,
                noiseSuppression: false,
                autoGainControl: false,
            }
        }).then(function (stream) {
            let audioSource = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            let scriptNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 0);
            scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function (audioProcessingEvent) {
                console.log('foo!');
            };
            audioSource.connect(scriptNode);

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Error initializing user media stream: ' + err);
        });
    }    
</script>

<button id="start" onclick="start()">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```

For whatever reason this does not constantly output "foo!" in the console. What am I missing?

EDIT: It works in Firefox but not Chrome. Confusing...

Comment: 'example 3' from this lib works every where <pc, ios, android>  
https://gersonrosales.github.io/Record-Audios-and-Videos-with-getUserMedia/

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that Chrome requires the Script Node to be connected to some sort of output to actually start processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `scriptNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)` did the trick on Chrome. Processing only starts if the script node is actually connected to some sort of output.

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue in Chrome. You must genreally connect a node directly or indirectly to the destination for it to process anything.  This is unlikely to get fixed since ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated and because 0 output channels is badly defined in the spec.